# DBMS_SESSION.set_client_identifier equivalent in SQL Server

Tags: sql-server, sessionid

I'd like to know if there's a way to set client identifier context like in Oracle by using `DBMS_SESSION.set_client_identifier` and grab the value using a function.

I am trying to track data changes including who/which username made the changes.
My plan to create Triggers that capture the OLD value, NEW value, and the username.

The connection to the server is using pooled connection, so using the username that connects to the DB is not the answer.

Anyone has an idea?

Answer (score 2):

If you cannot use properties from the connection itself (since it's pooled) you will have to set some additional info after your call to `connection.Open()`. But if I read your question correctly, that's OK for you.

So what you can use is SQL Servers `SET CONTEXT_INFO`, which lets you store up to 128 arbitrary bytes in the session/connection context and which you can query thereafter with the `CONTEXT_INFO()` function. See the description [>here<](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187768%28v=SQL.90%29.aspx).

Comment: Thank you. I think this does the trick. I'm planning on storing a user name since the connection will be coming from a web app for auditing and logging purposes. Since it accepts just a varbinary, I think I have to do this: Declare @test varbinary(128)
set @test =  convert(varbinary(128),'Jeremy')
SET CONTEXT_INFO @test